# Docker Registry with prefix has problem with Docker login

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-registry

I just deployed a Docker Registry on my personal server. I set up TLS and basic authentication as described in the main [Docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/registry/deploying/).

I am able to access the repository via URL by specifying `https://{HOST}/registry/v2`. It prompts the basic authentication request and returns an empty JSON `{}`.

Unfortunately, when I try to login to the registry via Docker CLI by using the following command

```sh
$ docker login https://{HOST}/registry/
```

it prompts the request for user and password, but after that it returns

```
Error response from daemon: login attempt to https://{HOST}/v2/ failed with status: 404 Not Found
```

completely ignoring the fact that the registry has a prefix and it is not in the root of the host.

Do you have an idea on how to fix this?

Here are the main file I used for the deployment.

## Deployment configuration files

### docker-compose.yaml

```yaml
version: '3.5'

services:
  registry:
    restart: always
    image: registry:2
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
    environment:
      REGISTRY_AUTH: htpasswd
      REGISTRY_AUTH_HTPASSWD_PATH: /auth/htpasswd
      REGISTRY_AUTH_HTPASSWD_REALM: Registry Realm
      REGISTRY_HTTP_PREFIX: /registry/
    volumes:
      - ./data:/var/lib/registry
      - ./auth:/auth
```

### nginx location configuration

```
location /registry/ {
        # Do not allow connections from docker 1.5 and earlier
        # docker pre-1.6.0 did not properly set the user agent on ping, catch "Go *" user agents
        if ($http_user_agent ~ "^(docker\/1\.(3|4|5(?!\.[0-9]-dev))|Go ).*$" ) {
            return 404;
        }

        proxy_pass                          http://localhost:5000;
        proxy_set_header  Host              $http_host;   # required for docker client's sake
        proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP         $remote_addr; # pass on real client's IP
        proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_read_timeout                  900;
    }
```

Comment: This used to be an open/known behaviour for long time. I'm not sure if it was ever fixed but if you are trying with latest version of registry, client and daemon versions and are still facing the issue, then I'm guessing it wasn't fixed. If so, your best bet is to not use a sub-path at all.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @ShashankV . It is a pity that the main docker CLI can not give this type of feature. I think that the most suitable shortcut is to use no subpath for the moment.